# Google Compute Engine Port 25 Outbound 'Bypass'?

Tags: linux, email, google-compute-engine, firewall

So I currently rent a hefty server with Google on their Compute Engine platform which costs me around $180 per month. I've never set up a mail server before and got to grips with Exim4 and had some pretty good success after a couple hours of troubleshooting after I found out that Google block [all outbound port 25 connections](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail).

Which obviously means I can't send emails from my email server, only receiving them. They then advise clients to use their partner email service [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com), in which Google offer a free tier to their existing customers of 25,000 emails per month for free, only problem is you have to pay another $80 per month to remove 'Whitelabeling', the "via" or "on behalf of" on **all** emails you send.

My question is what are my options in getting around this problem? The only one I can think of and what Google also suggest is to buy a VPN service from them and setup another mail server somewhere else, which is ridiculous as the price I pay for this sole server should come with unrestricted port access.

Comment: I'm in the exact same boat, except I'm using Alt-N's Mdaemon email server software.  I refuse to be forced into using "sendgrid".  If I find a way to get this done, I'll certainly reply back.

Comment: UPDATE:  So what I ended up doing was creating an AWS EC2 (Amazon) t2.micro instance.  It's free for the first 12 months, and they will allow all SMTP traffic.  I popped my email server there instead with wild success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with Mandrill from MailChimp https://www.mandrill.com/
We successfully use it with Postfix.

Answer (score 2):

As ssasa mentions you can use any email relay service that operates on non-standard ports, for example many providers allow submission on port 2525.

If you use Google Apps you can use GMail's relay service to send outbound mail without a "sent via".